# Getting a ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I see to have a problem with a for loop I have created.

```
    for (Rectangle rect  : Wall.wallRects){
        if(rect.intersects(Ball.ball)){
            System.out.println("Collied");
        }
    }
```

This throws this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
at com.thejacksullivan.breakout.Collison.checkCollison(Collison.java:14)
at com.thejacksullivan.breakout.Ball.moveBall(Ball.java:23)
at com.thejacksullivan.breakout.Core.main(Core.java:48)
```

It's called from:

```
public class Ball {

public static Rectangle ball;
public static int x = 250;
public static int y = 200;
public static int dx = 4;
public static int dy = 4;
public static int dia = 30;

public static void moveBall(){
    ball = new Rectangle(x, y, 15, 15);

    if(x + dx < 0 || x + dia + dx > Core.frame.getWidth()){
        dx *= -1;
    }
    if(y + dy < 0 || y + dia + dy > Core.frame.getHeight()) {
        dy *= -1;
    }
    Collison.checkCollison();
    x += dx;
    y += dy;


}
}
```

I'm not exactly sure how to fix this. I have used the same type of check for collision in similar programs, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Oh and the error lines are:

```
for (Rectangle rect  : Wall.wallRects){

Collison.checkCollison();

Ball.moveBall();
```

(I just realized I have been spelling the word Collision wrong, woops :D)

If you need any more info let me know.

Update:
I just moved my Collison.checkCollsion() to my paint() method. I believe it was not working correctly because I add my rects to Wall.rects in the paint method, so that is what was causing the error. Thanks for the help to all.

Comment: Someone, some where in you code, is modifying the list `Wall.wallRects` while you're trying to iterate the list

Comment: Is that actually the full code for `checkCollision()`?

Comment: The way `checkCollision` takes no arguments gets me worried because that means all your state is somehow global, so could be mutated from anywhere. `Ball.ball` and `Wall.wallRects` are more examples. Your entire design is OOP-contrary.

Comment: Also, what is the code for `rect.intersects()`?

Comment: @iamnotmaynard I did not make that method, I'm not sure what they are called but I think it's a method inside of swing.

Answer (score 0):

Another thread modifies Wall.wallRects array during your collision checks, to avoid this you need some kind of synchronization

in checkCollision function:

```
synchronized(Wall.wallRects)
{
for (Rectangle rect  : Wall.wallRects){
        if(rect.intersects(Ball.ball)){
            System.out.println("Collied");
        }
    }
}
```

and in all other places where Wall.wallRects are modified - add the same `synchronized()` block

UPDATE, thanks to @iamnotmaynard

If you're not using threads - then problem can be if you do some modifications to Wall.wallRects inside loop, for example:

```
for (Rectangle rect  : Wall.wallRects){
Ball.moveBall(); // - if the function somehow modifies wallRects, you have error
}
```

Comment: I don't know if there's reason to conclude there are any other threads in OP's code.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard agree, but it so common problem for beginners

Comment: Well, common for beginners using threads. I suspect one of the methods being called within the loop (in the same thread) is trying to change `rect` or `wallRects`.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard agree, updating the answer

Comment: Seems like a program with a UI, maybe new balls are appearing on the wall from a different thread while the collision detection is occurring?